# How to fire a function on dropdown change in React Class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have the following class component

```
import { React } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

import Button from '../components/button';
import { getData } from '../utils/debugger';

class InputForm extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isLoaded: false,
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { dropdown: 'RTS', value: '', data: this.data };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleDropdown = this.handleDropdown.bind(this);

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  }

  handleDropdown(event) {
    this.setState({ dropdown: event.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  // use comonentDidMount lifecycle method
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ isLoaded: true });
    console.log('loaded!');

    axios({
      method: 'GET',
      url: `http://xxx-xxx/xxx/${this.state.dropdown}`,
    })
      .then((response) => {
        const data = response.data;
        return data;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className='flex'>
        <select
          value={this.state.dropdown}
          onChange={this.handleDropdown}
          className='px-3 py-3 placeholder-gray-300 text-gray-600 relative bg-white rounded text-sm border-0 shadow outline-none focus:outline-none focus:ring w-full mr-2'>
          <option value='RTS'>RTS</option>
          <option value='RTB'>RTB</option>
          <option value='MPC'>MPC</option>
          <option value='MPC_DSP'>MPC_DSP</option>
        </select>

        <select
          value={this.state.value}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          className='px-3 py-3 placeholder-gray-300 text-gray-600 relative bg-white rounded text-sm border-0 shadow outline-none focus:outline-none focus:ring w-full mr-2'>
          {this.data.map((r) => (
            <option value={r.key.name}>{r.key.name}</option>
          ))}
        </select>

        <Button onClick={() => getData(this.state.dropdown, this.state.value)} color='green'>
          Generate
        </Button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default InputForm;
```

I would like to fire the axios on load and then populate the dropdown with the results. Like so...but i am not sure how to access `data` from the axios call so i can map over it. This is the first time using class components I normally use function ones so abit lost

```
<select
          value={this.state.value}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          className='px-3 py-3 placeholder-gray-300 text-gray-600 relative bg-white rounded text-sm border-0 shadow outline-none focus:outline-none focus:ring w-full mr-2'>
          {this.data.map((r) => (
            <option value={r.key.name}>{r.key.name}</option>
          ))}
        </select>
```

However I would also like to fire the same axios function call when this dropdown

```
<select
          value={this.state.dropdown}
          onChange={this.handleDropdown}
          className='px-3 py-3 placeholder-gray-300 text-gray-600 relative bg-white rounded text-sm border-0 shadow outline-none focus:outline-none focus:ring w-full mr-2'>
          <option value='RTS'>RTS</option>
          <option value='RTB'>RTB</option>
          <option value='MPC'>MPC</option>
          <option value='MPC_DSP'>MPC_DSP</option>
        </select>
```

is changed. As you can see I am calling the value here: `url: http://xxx-xxx/xxx/${this.state.dropdown}`

I guess what i am trying to do, is everytime the first drop down is changed, it calls the api to get the results and then populates that over to the 2nd dropdown so a user can select an item.

Any help on doing this would be great

**Update**

Thanks to the below I have managed to get a console log of the result but I have had to `JSON.stringify()` it as I was getting `[object Object]`

I have logged to the console this

```
<select
          value={this.state.value}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          className='px-3 py-3 placeholder-gray-300 text-gray-600 relative bg-white rounded text-sm border-0 shadow outline-none focus:outline-none focus:ring w-full mr-2'>
          {/* {this.state.data.map((r) => (
            <option key={r.key.name} value={r.key.name}>
              {r.key.name}
            </option>
          ))} */}
          {console.log(`result: ${JSON.stringify(this.state.data.data)}`)}
        </select>
```

As the `this.state.data.map((r)` didnt seem to work, so was curious to see what has happening. This `{console.log(result: ${JSON.stringify(this.state.data.data)})}` presents me with the desired results but i cant seem to get access to `key.name`

This is the result from the console log

```
result: [{"key":{"name":"THIS_IS_A_TEST","type":"RTS"},"creationTime":1626467969027,"expression":{"condition":"AND","rules":[{"field":"environment_host","operator":"EQUAL","value":"1"}]},"logSize":2,"logTimeSeconds":900,"expireSeconds":7200,"captureRawData":false}]
```

So i guess i have two questions.

1. why cant i seem to access `key.name`
2. why did I have to use `data.data` instead of just `this.state.data`
3. how can i use `JSON.Stringify()` when i get the data from data

Comment: What's the second drop down doing here and what it's supposed to do?

Comment: What response data are you getting from the axios call? Could you kindly provide some example? Is the structure like this data = [{key: {name: "Any name"}}, {key: {name: "Any name"}}, {key: {name: "Any name"}}]

Comment: yup the structure is `[{key:{name: ...}, ]` the 2nd dropdown is to be populated via the axios call so the value can be sent to another function

Answer (score 1):

Hope this solves the problem. Let me know if it works.

```js
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

import Button from "../components/button";
import { getData } from "../utils/debugger";

// Make a separate function for axios call so that you can reuse it
function queryData(dropdownValue) {
  return axios({
    method: "GET",
    url: `http://xxx-xxx/xxx/${dropdownValue}`,
  });
}

class InputForm extends React.Component {
  // Just use the state property. No need to use constructor
  state = {
    isLoaded: false,
    dropdown: "RTS",
    value: "",
    data: [],
  };

  // If you use arrow function then you don't have to
  // bind them in the constructor

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  };

  handleDropdown = async (event) => {
    // Here we need to query the data from axios
    // If we get the data then we'll update the state
    // otherwise you may show any error message
    const value = event.target.value;
    try {
      const newData = await queryData(value);
      this.setState({ data: newData, dropdown: value });
    } catch (ex) {
      console.error("Could not get data from axios");
    }
  };

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    queryData(this.state.dropdown)
      .then((data) => this.setState({ data, isLoaded: true }))
      .catch(() => {
        this.setState({ isLoaded: false });
        // Do other stuff here, may be show any error message?
        // Could not get data
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="flex">
        <select
          value={this.state.dropdown}
          onChange={this.handleDropdown}
          className="px-3 py-3 placeholder-gray-300 text-gray-600 relative bg-white rounded text-sm border-0 shadow outline-none focus:outline-none focus:ring w-full mr-2"
        >
          <option value="RTS">RTS</option>
          <option value="RTB">RTB</option>
          <option value="MPC">MPC</option>
          <option value="MPC_DSP">MPC_DSP</option>
        </select>

        <select
          value={this.state.value}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          className="px-3 py-3 placeholder-gray-300 text-gray-600 relative bg-white rounded text-sm border-0 shadow outline-none focus:outline-none focus:ring w-full mr-2"
        >
          {this.state.data.map((r) => (
            <option key={r.key.name} value={r.key.name}>
              {r.key.name}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>

        <Button
          onClick={() => getData(this.state.dropdown, this.state.value)}
          color="green"
        >
          Generate
        </Button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default InputForm;
```

## Update

@mrpbennett the reason why you've to use <kbd>data.data</kbd> is probably axios returns the response in the data propery. and that's why you can't access key.name. You've to do <kbd>this.state.data.data[0].key.name</kbd>! But I recommend modifying the queryData function as the following and hopefully everything would work fine.

```js
function queryData(dropdownValue) {
  return axios
  .get(`http://xxx-xxx/xxx/${dropdownValue}`)
  .then(res => res.data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I am getting `TypeError: this.state.data.map is not a function`  it seems to be around the 2nd dropdown

Comment: Then data must be undefined or null. If you're not getting any data from the api then just set it to an empty array! Still can't solve it? Just use the debugger to pin point the error. As I don't have access to your api I can't solve the whole problem for you!

Comment: I have included my next issue in my original post